# How to embed a list into a list in Groovy, given some conditions?

Tags: groovy

I have a groovy code like this :

```
main = []
b="ogodtsneeencs"
def input = ["go", "good", "do", "sentences", "tense", "scen"]
(0..(input.size()-1)).each{ Sp(input[it]) }
def Sp(def a)
{
        flag = false
        list = []
        (0..(a.size()-1)).collect { list << a[it] }
        ans = list.permutations().each { temp =  it.join()
                                           if(b.find("$temp"))
                                           {
                                                main << it
                                                flag = true
                                           }
}
        if(flag == false)
                main << null

}
println main
```

which outputs :

```
[[o, g], [g, o], [o, g, o, d], [o, d], [t, s, n, e, e, e, n, c, s], [t, s, n, e, e], [e, n, c, s]]
```

The thing I'm doing here is to find the possible permutations that have occurred in `b` using the `input`. And I'm getting the output as needed. But if the output is noticed carefully, for the same input `go` i.e(`input[0]`) produces the first two outputs i.e `main[0] and main[1]`. Since to keep a index kind of way(i.e for which `input` which output `main` is produced), how I can change the above code, so that the output returns like this :

```
[[[o, g], [g, o]], [o, g, o, d], [o, d], [t, s, n, e, e, e, n, c, s], [t, s, n, e, e], [e, n, c, s]]
```

Indicating that the first both outputs is same from same input, in our case it is `input[0]`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Artur's solution can be further groovified to:

```
def Sp(a) {
  (a as List).permutations().findAll { s -> b.find( s.join() ) }
}
```

Comment: this seems to be much `Groovier`

Answer (score 2):

I've also simplified your code a bit:

```
b="ogodtsneeencs"
def input = ["go", "good", "do", "sentences", "tense", "scen"]
main = input.collect { Sp(it) }
def Sp(a) {
  def list = a as List
  def result = []
  list.permutations().each {
    if (b.find(it.join())) result << it
  }
  result
}
```

This would output:

```
[[[o, g], [g, o]], [[o, g, o, d]], [[o, d]], [[t, s, n, e, e, e, n, c, s]], [[t, s, n, e, e]], [[e, n, c, s]]]
```

If you'd like to have all the singleton sets without the enclosing set (as you wrote in your  example, although I find it as a bit impractical), then you can just swap the last line of `Sp` to:

```
result.size() == 1 ? result[0] : result
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work as expected!! Returns the same output as my code does!

Comment: Maybe you mistyped something? Try running it from [here](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/575002)

Comment: Sorry, ya this code is working. But can you explain how this works? How you made your code to embed the list as I have asked for it?

Comment: Function `Sp` is returning a list now (referenced by `result`), that is filled with all the matching permutations. So in line 3 we're constructing a list of lists.